# hibernate query not giving the expected result

Tags: sql, hibernate

**I want to read the users based on there firstname match with passed character  I wrote Hibernate Criteria query for same but its not giving me the output it returns 0 rows` ProjectionList projections = Projections.projectionList()
                                .add(Projections.id().as("id"))
    .add(Projections.property("firstName").as("firstName"))
.add(Projections.property("lastName").as("lastName"))

```
                      long a=4;
                        Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(UserInfo.class)
                        .createAlias("blist", "embeddedObj") 
                        .add(Restrictions.ilike("firstName",name))
                        .add(Restrictions.ne("embeddedObj.userid",a))
                        .setProjection(projections)
                        .setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanNestedResultTransformer(UserInfo.class));
                      userInfos =(List<UserInfo>)cr.list();` **
```

here is the sql query genrated by the hibernate for the same

```
select this_.id as y0_, this_.firstName as y1_, this_.lastName as y2_,  from Users this_ inner join USER_BLOCKUSERS embeddedob1_ on this_.id=embeddedob1_.USER_ID where lower(this_.firstName) like ? and![this is the user table![\]\[1\]][1] embeddedob1_.userid<>?
```

Comment: So, what does the table contain, and what is the value of name?

Comment: I have users with column like firstName ,lastname etc and have another table user_blist which having column id(primary key),userid,user_id(foreign key),

Comment: But what are the **values** in that table? And what is the value of `name`?

Comment: @JB Nizet  having firstName like amit,anil,abhi,sunil,neha,viraj,yogesh user will pass the value of name is 'a' so it has to return me amit,anil only.cause the user who is  searching for 'a' is blocked by abhi so that abhi wont come in result. the blocking relation I maintain in another table user_blist

Answer (score 1):

```
'anil' like 'a'
```

is false. It would be true if the name was `a%`, or `%a%`, depending on what you want: names starting with a, or names containing a.

Comment: name starting with 'a'

Comment: So, as my answer says, name must contain `a%`, not `a`. You really need to *read* the answers and comments. It helps a lot.

Comment: I want starting with 'a'. but I tried with contain also but it does not give me any record I am printing the result size on console it gives 0

Comment: @AbhiJadhav, as JB suggests the `name`  variable should hold the value `a%` or `%a%`. This will give you results where name starts with `a` and where name has letter `a`. Have you tried this option? Read the answer carefully.